# ApplicationUpdaterUI worked in 1.5 not Air 2.7

Tags: air

I have followed below steps to make my project workable, but still I am facing below issue:-
Steps followed

1. Update your project to build with the Flex 3.5a SDK
   http://opensource.adobe.com/wiki/display/flexsdk/Download+Flex+3
2. Overlay the AIR 2 SDK over your existing Flex SDK
   See this article: http://kb2.adobe.com/cps/495/cpsid_49532.html
3. Copy only the applicationupdater_ui.swc from the AIR 2 SDK over the one inside the Flex SDK.

   - The applicationupdater_ui.swc can be found in /frameworks/libs/air/applicationupdater_ui.swc
   - Get the AIR 2 SDK from here http://www.adobe.com/cfusion/entitlement/index.cfm?e=airsdk
   - Copy the applicationupdater_ui.swc from the AIR 2 SDK over the one inside the Flex SDK
4. Remove the reference to the Flex SDK applicationupdater_ui.swc from the Flex project and add a new swc reference to the one in the AIR 2 SDK (this swc can be copied in a 'libs' folder directly into your project).

Is there any setting changes need to be done or any work around for the solution?

Environment: - Flex 3.0, SDK 3.5 and AIR SDK 2.7

Comment: is there a reason why you are not using the latest Flex SDK?

Comment: Our current(age of project 3-years) project is build on Flex 3, SDK 3.0 and AIR 1.5 and we are planning to make it compactable with Flex 3/Flex 4, SDK 3.5 and AIR 2.7(Latest) where we don’t have to change much code, which will help us to make our application more faster.

Answer (score 0):

The update XML changed in AIR 2.5.  [This](http://kb2.adobe.com/cps/873/cpsid_87300.html) knowledge base article explains how to update your application to handle it.

Comment: Not able to popup auto-update popup -
As per your suggestion and link provided by you, I have modified update.xml file, but still I am facing the same issue. I tried by using SDK 3.4, SDK 3.5 and SDK 3.6 by copying “applicationupdater_ui.swc” file from SDK 3.5a in to /frameworks/libs/air/ folder of SDK. 
--Update.xml--
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?> 
<update xmlns="http://ns.adobe.com/air/framework/update/description/2.5">
<versionNumber>v1.1</versionNumber> 
<url>https://serverURL/myApp.air</url> 
<description>
<![CDATA[ 
 Major changes to application
]]> 
</description>
</update>

Comment: In that case it sounds like it's time to put on your debugging hat and start digging around.  Some places I'd start looking: 1) make sure your app is not being blocked by your firewall 2) add listeners for all the events that the updater fires and make sure it's not erroring out somewhere.